# Creating a Raw Socket Client to connect to a web host

Tags: c++, c, macos, sockets, raw-sockets

I would like to write a raw socket, in order for it connect to a website on a specific port and retrieve any information the site has:

I wrote the code so far, but not sure where to enter the host name and port information (Ex: abc.xyz.com:8096)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


void dump(const unsigned char *data_buffer, const unsigned int length);

int main (void)
{

    int i, recv_length, fd;
  u_char buffer[10000];
  if((fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_TCP))==-1)
     perror("-1 Return \n");
  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    recv_length = recv(fd,buffer,10000,0);
    printf("Got a %d byte packet\n", recv_length);
    dump(buffer, recv_length);  
    
}
}

void dump(const unsigned char *data_buffer, const unsigned int length) {
   unsigned char byte;
   unsigned int i, j;
   for(i=0; i < length; i++) {
     byte = data_buffer[i];
     printf("%02x ", data_buffer[i]); 
     if(((i%16)==15) || (i==length-1)) {
       for(j=0; j < 15-(i%16); j++)
       printf(" ");
       printf("| ");
        for(j=(i-(i%16)); j <= i; j++) { 
         byte = data_buffer[j];
         if((byte > 31) && (byte < 127)) 
         printf("%c", byte);
     else
      printf(".");
     }
     printf("\n"); 
    } 
   } 
}
```

I am also getting a segmentation fault after the tcp dump. Not sure how to fix that, but the primary issue is where to define the hostname and port I want to connect to

Comment: you cannot `recv`/`send` whatever, before `connect`/`bind` ing to a valid address. The address is gotten through `getaddrinfo`. Please consider reading a networking guide such as [beej's guide to network programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/pdf/bgnet_a4_c_1.pdf)

Comment: SOCK_RAW is the wrong type of socket to use for this task. Use SOCK_STREAM instead. And then connect() to the desired host ip/port. Then review [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) and related docs for how the HTTP protocol works, as that is what you need to use to request data and receive it over the connected socket connection.